# Hair is opaque when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, hair

I followed the tutorial to learn how to create low poly hair, but in cycles, the alpha part of the hair will be displayed as black because of the overlay. So I searched and found that the solution is to increase the transparency in the light paths, which can solve the overlapping face Black problem, but this doesn't work in rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you have set way more particles in render then viewport and in this case, either decrease child particles for render

[image]

or add more Transparent passes, 64 is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for you help:)